# Why is `groupby` with `as_index=False` even slower than `groupby` with `reset_index`

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, pandas-groupby

I just recently came across this strange Pandas behavior with `groupby`.

I have this dataframe:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]})
>>> df
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
3  1  7
4  2  8
5  3  9
>>>
```

And I want to `groupby` the column `a` and `sum` the column `b`.

Normal `groupby` would have the column as index, but `as_index=False` won't:

```
>>> df.groupby('a')['b'].sum()
a
1    11
2    13
3    15
Name: b, dtype: int64
>>>
```

---

But when I time them:

```
>>> timeit(lambda: df.groupby('a')['b'].sum(), number=1000)
0.5426476000000093
>>> timeit(lambda: df.groupby('a')['b'].sum(), number=10000)
4.912795499999902
>>> timeit(lambda: df.groupby('a', as_index=False)['b'].sum(), number=1000)
1.419923899999958
>>> timeit(lambda: df.groupby('a', as_index=False)['b'].sum(), number=10000)
11.907147600000144
>>>
```

You can see that for some reason, `groupby` with `as_index=False` is 2.75x slower!

Not just that! It's even slower than `reset_index`!

```
>>> timeit(lambda: df.groupby('a', as_index=False)['b'].sum(), number=1000)
1.419923899999958
>>> timeit(lambda: df.groupby('a', as_index=False)['b'].sum(), number=10000)
11.907147600000144
>>> timeit(lambda: df.groupby('a')['b'].sum().reset_index(), number=1000)
1.0641113000001496
>>> timeit(lambda: df.groupby('a')['b'].sum().reset_index(), number=10000)
10.01520289999985
>>>
```

And `reset_index` obviously also gives the same output as `as_index=False`:

```
>>> df.groupby('a')['b'].sum().reset_index()
   a   b
0  1  11
1  2  13
2  3  15
>>>
```

`as_index=False`:

```
>>> df.groupby('a', as_index=False)['b'].sum()
   a   b
0  1  11
1  2  13
2  3  15
>>>
```

I can understand that `as_index=False` might be slower, but not this much slower... Also the main thing is that I can't wrap my head around that why is `reset_index` faster? That's an extra function...

Why is this? What is the implementation of `as_index`?

I am really surprised, I even thought that it's very possible that `as_index=False` would be faster than `as_index=True`, since it doesn't need a column to be set as the index.

But it's the opposite, it's actually `as_index=True` being 2.75 times faster... And even `reset_index` being faster than `as_index=False`.

If this is the case why doesn't `as_index=False` also just simply use `reset_index`?

Comment: this will be a great opportunity for you to look at the source code and possibly submit a PR to fix this. power to open source!

Comment: @sammywemmy True, will look into it!

Comment: @sammywemmy This is honestly for me a interesting  question :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`as_index=True` is the default as the grouper uses internally an index and resets it if `as_index` is set to`False`:

cf. [`core.groupby.py` source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.3.3/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py)

```
        if not self.as_index:
            self._insert_inaxis_grouper_inplace(result)
```

The time difference between `True`/`False` is actually minimal, you should use a larger dataframe to test the speed.

Here on 600k rows:

`True`:  `30.7 ms ± 3.05 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`

`False`: `32.5 ms ± 2.66 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each`

The difference is thus not proportional (2 times slower), but rather fixed (2.5 ms slower), which is less a burden.

Now as to why the source doesn't use `reset_index`, well pandas does a lot of things internally, I am only guessing here as the code is complex, but there are likely many checks in place that do more things than just resetting the index.

Comment: Cool, but it would be nice to know why is `reset_index` faster.

Comment: Just the note... Where did you fine that line? which line :)

Comment: Added an example of the `_insert_inaxis_grouper_inplace` function.

Answer (score 0):

Assign to @mozway's answer, the `_insert_inaxis_grouper_inplace` function is:

```
def _insert_inaxis_grouper_inplace(self, result: DataFrame) -> None:
    # zip in reverse so we can always insert at loc 0
    columns = result.columns
    for name, lev, in_axis in zip(
        reversed(self.grouper.names),
        reversed(self.grouper.get_group_levels()),
        reversed([grp.in_axis for grp in self.grouper.groupings]),
    ):
        # GH #28549
        # When using .apply(-), name will be in columns already
        if in_axis and name not in columns:
            result.insert(0, name, lev)
```

As you can see, it's using `insert`, not reset index.

So I suspect if it uses:

```
def _insert_inaxis_grouper_inplace(self, result: DataFrame) -> None:
    # zip in reverse so we can always insert at loc 0
    columns = result.columns
    for name, lev, in_axis in zip(
        reversed(self.grouper.names),
        reversed(self.grouper.get_group_levels()),
        reversed([grp.in_axis for grp in self.grouper.groupings]),
    ):
        # GH #28549
        # When using .apply(-), name will be in columns already
        if in_axis and name not in columns:
            result = result.reset_index()
```

Not completely sure about the setup though, but I expect the above to work...

Then it probably would be faster.